# regex - must not allow whitespaces in front of text but allows null values

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried this but it doesn't allow value to be null:

```
[^-\s][Ñña-zA-Z .\-\,]*$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "null" you mean empty, that's because your regex requires at least one character from your first character class.

If you want to allow blank, you can do it with an alternation (`|`):

```
[^-\s][Ñña-zA-Z .\-\,]*$|^$
```

The `|` means "or" and the `^$` means "blank." [Details on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oG4uG3/1).